# This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type int

Tags: ocaml

I have a bug in my program in OCaml and I am looking for help.

the error:

```
This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type int
```

The line error with the error contains `soma = soma`

```
let soma = 0;;
let rec nBell n = 
if n == 0 then 1 
    else
        for k=0 to n-1 do 
        soma = soma + ((fact(n-1)/(fact(k)*fact((n-1)-k))) * nBell(k));
            done;;`
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 10):

As has recently been mentioned here quite a few times, OCaml has no statements. It only has expressions. For an `if` expression to make sense, the `then` and `else` parts have to be the same type. In your code the `then` part is `1`. I.e., it has type `int`. In the `else` part you have a `for` expression. The type of a `for` expression is `unit`. So that's what the compiler is complaining about.

However, fixing this problem will be just the first step, as your code is based on a misunderstanding of how OCaml variables work. OCaml variables like `soma` are *immutable*. You can't change their value. So the expression `soma = soma + 1` is actually a *comparison* that tells whether the two values are equal:

```
# let soma = 0;;
val soma : int = 0
# soma = soma + 1;;
- : bool = false
```

Generally speaking, you need to find a way to solve your problem without assigning to variables; i.e., without changing their values.

If you're just starting with functional programming, this seems absurd. However it turns out just to be another way to look at things.